# How to set global state for flutter app using MobX without use of provider?

Tags: flutter, singleton, mobx

I want to have global variables in my app and their values set using MobX without use of providers. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use provider then you can go with there alternative package [Modular](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_modular). It will make your work easy and you can easily different modules as well.